# How does for-range construct relate to closures in Go?

Tags: for-loop, go, range, closures

Is there any relation between for-range and closures in Go?
I think that for-range **can be thought of** as using a closure.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any relation between for-range and closures in Go?

No.

(The only thing to remember is that the loop variables are reused on each iteration an closures *inside* the for loop will all close over the same variable. See https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines)

Answer (score -3):

A possible answer could be this code that has the same behavior. Firstly, I use a closure and secondly, I use a for-range loop.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    names := [4]string{"John", "Marie", "David", "Alex"}

    iter := generator(names)
    for true {
        i, v := iter()
        fmt.Printf("%v %s\n", i, v)

        if i == 3 {
            break
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("---------------------------------")

    for i, v := range names {
        fmt.Printf("%v %s\n", i, v)
    }
}

func generator(arr [4]string) func() (int, string) {

    index := 0

    return func() (int, string) {

        nextName := arr[index]
        index++
        return index - 1, nextName
    }
}
```